# Json Deserialization of List VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm having trouble deserializing a JSON file that has an array. I can get it to work fine if I take one of the people into its own JSON string and put it into the People class. However, when I do multiple, it does not work and simply returns an empty object every time. I need the multiple string to work with no changes to the JSON, as that is what I am receiving. Is there anything in DataContract or DataMember that I am doing wrong when calling these?

Working JSON string with People class = {""name"":""J.Lane"",""att"":1}

Not Working JSON string with PeopleList class = {""people"":{""00-0029619"":{""name"":""J.Lane"",""att"":1},""00-0021206"":{""name"":""J.Street"",""att"":3}}}

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class PeopleList
    <DataMember(Name:="people")> _
    Public People_List As List(Of People)
End Class

<DataContract()> _
Public Class People
    <DataMember(Name:="name")> _
    Public Person_Name As String

    <DataMember(Name:="att")> _
    Public Attempts As String
End Class

Public Sub ScrapeFile()
    Try
        Dim thisScrape As New PeopleList
        thisScrape = DirectCast(JSONSerialization.jsonDeserializeURI(Of PeopleList)("http://www.sitenotusedyet.com"), PeopleList)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Shit")
    End Try
End Sub

Public Shared Function JsonDeserialize(Of T)(jsonString As String) As T
        Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(T))
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString))
        Dim obj As T = DirectCast(ser.ReadObject(ms), T)
        Return obj
End Function

Public Shared Function jsonDeserializeURI(Of T)(ByVal strURI As String) As T
        Dim strHTML As String
        Dim objWC As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim obj As T
        Try
            obj = JSONSerialization.JsonDeserialize(Of T)("{""people"":{""00-0029619"":{""name"":""J.Lane"",""att"":1},""00-0021206"":{""name"":""J.Street"",""att"":3}}}")
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
        Return obj
End Function
```

Comment: There's no square brackets `[ ]` in your JSON, so there's no array.

Comment: So if that is what I am getting, how do I separate those out?

Answer (score 0):

The form of your json is not `List(Of People)` it's a `Dictionary(Of String, People)`

so basically this; `Public People_List As List(Of People)`

needs to be; `Public People_Dict As Dictionary(Of String, People)`

And if you pass that type into your deserialize method everything should work fine (or at least it will take you past your current error).

EDIT: Next error;

This;

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class People
    <DataMember(Name:="name")> _
    Public Person_Name As String

    <DataMember(Name:="att")> _
    Public Attempts As String
End Class
```

need to be 
     _
    Public Class People
         _
        Public Person_Name As String

```
    <DataMember(Name:="att")> _
    Public Attempts As Int
End Class
```

because the value of att is not quoted, it is clearly not a string. I should have noticed that yesterday. Anyway, if you're unfamiliar with mapping json to objects in .NET I might recommend familiarizing yourself with some of the material here http://www.json-schema.org/

If you can fluently understand the schema of json it makes it a lot easier to say something like 'that's a dictionary of dictionarys which have has objects in it that should have these properties' or whatever.

Comment: That makes sense, but it is still producing nothing in the obj when I made that change.

Comment: @user2962864 can you verify the contents of the `MemoryStream` you're passing to `ReadObject`? Seems like you're code should be working now... Maybe you need `Dim obj As New T` though? If that does nothing I'd guess you got a problem with your memory stream but I'm not positive. You in code model matches the json fine so that's definitely no longer the problem.

Comment: I changed it to Public People_Dict As Dictionary(Of People, String) and it is now at least giving me a count = 0 instead of nothing.

Comment: @user2962864 Oh I just noticed your other problem which is that `att` is a number in json which means it should probably be an `int` in your model.

Comment: That did not work for this either. I ended up having to restructure everything through newtonsoft and got it working properly.